# Restlet with Same Path and Different Verbs

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I have the following interesting situation. I have one path with three verbs: GET, DELETE, POST. They correspond to three routes in Camel context. My observation is that if the three routes are in the same Camel Context, every works well. But if the routes are in different camel contexts, only one of them works. So far, I noticed that DELETE wworks and the two others stop working. My example context is below:

```
<camel:camelContext  id="get-test" autoStartup="true">

        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=DELETE"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Delete</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=GET"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Get</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=POST"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Post</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

So, the above is the working scenario. The scenario that does not work is below with three different contexts:

```
<camel:camelContext  id="delete-test" autoStartup="true">

        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=DELETE"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Delete</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>

<camel:camelContext  id="get-test" autoStartup="true">

        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=GET"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Get</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>

</camel:camelContext>

<camel:camelContext  id="post-test" autoStartup="true">


        <camel:route>
            <camel:from uri="restlet:/path?restletMethod=POST"></camel:from>
            <camel:transform>
                <camel:constant>Hi Post</camel:constant>
             </camel:transform>
        </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Maybe I am missing something in the camel spec that forbid this kind of configuration?

Comment: i also faced same problems with Apache CXF and Camel. Had to do it within same camel context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is not supported. The logic that selects the route to process the message only uses the context path as part of the logic.

Not sure how easy it would be to add restletMethod as well as part of that selection logic. Feel free to log a JIRA ticket, and dive into the code to contribute. We love contributions:
http://camel.apache.org/contributing

Comment: Good to know. i will look at the core and see what i can find. In the same vain, I noticed that within the same camel context, two restlet endpoints with the same number of parameters and different verbs, only work if the parameters have the same name. That means: restlet:/foo/{id}?restletMethod=POST and   restlet:/foo/{id}?restletMethod=GET will work on two different endpoints while restlet:/foo/{id}?restletMethod=POST and   restlet:/foo/{email}?restletMethod=GET does not work. Not sure if this is related to the logic you mentioned above.